# Вопросы про dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio

1. Можно ли как-то при добавлении .lib файлов в проект, чтобы .dll автоматически создавалась при компиляции, а не перетаскивать вручную
2. Как можно указать путь ко всем .dll в проекте? Т.е, например, у меня dll в `project/dlls/*.dll`, как мне указать линковщику, где лежат .dll?

Comment: 1. lib файлы не надо добавлять в проект 2. линковщик не использует dll

Comment: @user7860670 я имел ввиду, когда используешь lib, чтобы собрать проект

Comment: @user7860670 когда запускаю exe, у меня требуются dll файлы, которые лежат  в корне, я хочу поместить в какую-нибудь папку, но как мне указать exe, где лежат эти dll?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: @user7860670 а что насчет компиляции .lib в .dll?

Comment: Не понял вопроса...

Comment: @user7860670 Ну, я вот добавил .h и .lib файлы в проект, скомпилировал, у меня требует .dll, могу ли я сделать так, чтоб при компиляции, все dll добавились ко мне в проект

Comment: .dll надо добавлять не в проект, а в те места, где их ищет загрузчик при выполнении exe

Comment: @user7860670 в папку с проектом `project/dlls/*.dll`